# How can I use a private node on Wolfram Warptangent?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, remote-access, light-wallet

I'm using the instructions found on https://www.moneroclub.com/node with no luck. Are these commands still used in monero-wallet-cli?

Answer (score 5):

First thing to note is that `simplewallet` was renamed to `monero-wallet-cli` in Wolfram Warptangent. Secondly, it could be that the node is currently offline. There are other remote nodes available [here](http://moneroworld.com/). To quote:

> node.moneroworld.com are nodes that are from Monero long-term community members, so high trust level
>
> 2nodez.moneroworld.com are nodes from anyone (includes the nodes in node.moneroworld.com)
>
> Connect to a random remote node by pointing your wallet to node.moneroworld.com or 2nodez.moneroworld.com, using the following commands:
>
> (linux / unix-type)
>
> ./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host node.moneroworld.com
>
> or ./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host 2nodez.moneroworld.com
>
> (windows)
>
> monero-wallet-cli.exe --daemon-host node.moneroworld.com
>
> or monero-wallet-cli.exe --daemon-host 2nodez.moneroworld.com
>
> or download [this file](http://moneroworld.com/startwallet.bat) to your monero folder and double click on it.
>
> Remote nodes are secure - they can't spend your money. You do sacrifice privacy though, and you really should be running your own node, you know, because decentralization. But I understand that convenience wins out.

Note that you have to launch `monero-wallet-cli` from the terminal (on Linux and mac OS X) or from the command prompt (on Windows) with the aforementioned commands. To open the command prompt on Windows you have to go to the folder `monero-cli-wallet` is located and make sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files. Subsequently do SHIFT + right click and it will give you an option to "Open command window here".

Answer (score 0):

the command line arguments are the same aside from substituting `monero-wallet-cli` for `simplewallet`